# Pandas read_html gives me Permission denied(403)

Tags: python, pandas

I signed up to get currency price via a provider. When I use pd.read_html('URL') I get 403 error - permission denied. So I then tried to emulate a browser by doing this-

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import html5lib
import requests
%matplotlib inline

### Pretend to be a browser ###
url = 'URL_TO_PROVIDER_WITH_TOKEN'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

currency = pd.read_html('r')
```

However this gives me "no tables found". The source looks like this -

```
{"status":true,"currency":[{"currency":"GBP\/CAD","value":"1.7136","date":"2019-01-18 17:19:58","type":"original"}]}
```

What do I do wrong?

#### EDIT

If there are no tables in source file, how then can I get data into Pandas? As you can see the data I would like to "parse" looks like this (json)

```
{"status":true,"currency":[{"currency":"GBP\/CAD","value":"1.7136","date":"2019-01-18 17:19:58","type":"original"}]}
```

#### EDIT

Ok obvious the source was not html and had no tables in it. Therefor JSON was the way to go.
I managed to save the JSON structure with

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()
```

But then I am stuck. Output of r looks like this -

```
{'status': True,
 'currency': [{'currency': 'GBP/CAD',
   'value': '1.7083',
   'date': '2019-01-18 22:59:58',
   'type': 'original'}]}
```

How do I get columns to dataframe?
I want 'currency': 'GBP/CAD', 'value': '1.7083' and 'date': '2019-01-18 22:59:58'

#### EDIT - SOLUTION

```
url = 'URL_API_TOKEN'
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()

data = json_normalize(r['currency'])
```

Comment: 403 - http means FORBIDDEN. This means that you or your IP is not allowed to access the that link.

Comment: You probably hit the provider's server with too many requests. Look in your provider agreement to see how much traffic you are allowed to generate. And ask them to unban you.

Comment: Working fine when accessing via browser, so NO ban. However accessing via python gives me 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Maybe I get this error "no tables" because there ARE NO tables in source web adress. How to parse it then in pandas if source look like this (json?)

```
{"status":true,"currency":[{"currency":"GBP\/CAD","value":"1.7136","date":"2019-01-18 17:19:58","type":"original"}]}

```

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't be using `.text`. If `.text` returns you a json like structure, it's because you should probably use `requests.get(your_url).json()`. And then, do `pd.read_json()` to read the answer. Tell me if that works and i'll post this as an answer. :)

Comment: IMCoin - Think we are half way there =) r variable  now contains the parsed json.
r = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()

Comment: Well, I knew the answer but you didn't ping me using @ so I didn't see your comment. ;) -- I'm glad you found by yourself though ! I'll give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :
currency = pd.read_html(r)

instead of :
currency = pd.read_html('r')

because you call the method read_html with the string "r" as argument and not the variable r

SLP

Comment: Tried that - gives me "TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'Response'"

Comment: currency = pd.read_html(r.text) gives me ValueError: No tables found